# Error when trying to move the content store in alfresco

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, alfresco-share

Here is what I did, I tried moving my `content store` and `contentstore.deleted` from alfresco installation path to a new network location. I modified my `global.properties` like this.

```
dir.root=C:/Alfresco/alf_data
dir.contentstore=//server1/c/contentstore/contentstore
dir.contentstore.deleted=//server1/c/contentstore/contentstore.deleted
```

But tomcat was not able to read the location

**Update1**

I managed to solve the error partially:

(Initially I added permission to the folder alone in server and it was not working) and then 
I added permission to the drive (the drive in which the folder is located that is C drive)and I am able to solve.

But why tomcat is not able to read the shared folder directly? How to read the shared folder directly without giving permission to the entire drive

Comment: Hi Sameer, like I asked are you 100% positive that location //server1/c/contentstore/contentstore is reachable and writable by the user who starts Alfresco?

Comment: @TahirMalik  It is server machine. I shared the C drive of that server machine and I am pointing to this location only

Comment: @TahirMalik I even added everyone in the C drive share and granted full permission

Comment: The Log in your question shows nothing regarding a problem with your content store ...it's just a problem with your google docs subsystem.
You should upload the full log somewhere & post the link here

Comment: @alfrescian I updated the question please check

Comment: @alfrescian the file system of the server is different. Will it cause any issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help or not.
Alfresco stores references & configs in their DB, that way an Enterprise edition can change values via JMX rather than changing the alfresco-global.properties.

So there might be a possibility that these properties are saved there and aren't updated.

I'd personally do the following, one can be a possible solution:

1. If it's a vanilla system (so no important data): drop the db, create new clean db, remove the solr/lucene indexes & remove the contentstore & contentstore.deleted files and start Alfresco.
2. Do a reindex of Solr/Lucene
3. In windows or Linux map your server contentstore & contentstore deleted to the old location. In Linux it's ln -s (maybe you'll get some security issue, there is a fix for that). In windows via Disk management you can map locations to folders (google the way to do that)
4. Why don't you just mount in Windows a new Drive letter to the share? Mount it to for example Z:\ and let Alfresco write it to that directory

Comment: are you saying to delete the entire alf-data folder and to start the alfresco again?

Comment: Read point 1, I quote "remove the contentstore & contentstore.deleted files" So no don't remove alf_data in that folder there is Solr installed & the keystore folder which is needed.

Comment: how to delete old db, I have postgre and I clicked pg admin but there is no option to drop db

Comment: Do research. I guess for you it's better to uninstall Alfresco and install it again and on the last step don't start it. Then move the directories and change the alfresco-global.properties

Comment: Tahir when I move the content store to D drive in the same machine I am not getting any error. When I am moving to network location I am getting error

Comment: i've updated the answer, btw this is No Alfresco issue, but something with permission on your environment.